# JavaFX EventHandler within a method - not returning updated String

Tags: java, javafx, keyboard-events

I'm creating a text adventure game within a Javafx GUI. I display the question asking the user what their name is in a Text object, then display a TextField below it for the user to type their name. These objects are within a Vbox. I'm using an event handler to get the text from the TextField when the user presses enter. Once the first name and last name have been given the Text object should look like this, with the cleared text field underneath

What is your first name?
Joe

What is your last name?
Bloggs

Welcome....

This works ok until the user enters their last name. Instead of adding the last name underneath as it did with the first name, it changes the first name to the last name, and doesn't add either the last name or the next line (Welcome...) :

What is your first name?
Bloggs

What is your last name?

I create the TextField and Text objects in the start() method and pass them as parameters to a new Class, which launches the game:

```
game = new Game();
game.play(textField, text, vbox);

public class Game {
    private String firstname;
    private String surname;
    private TextProcessing textProcessing;
    private String currentText;
    private String nextText;

    public Game() {
        firstname = "";
        surname = "";
        textProcessing = new TextProcessing();
        currentText = "";
        nextText = "";
    }

    public void play(TextField textField, Text text, VBox vbox) {
        //Get the user's first name.
        text.setText("What is your first name?");
        currentText = text.getText();
        nextText = "\nWhat is your surname?";
        firstname = textProcessing.processText(textField, text,    
            currentText, nextText, vbox);

        //Get the user's last name.
        if(!firstname.equals("")) {
            currentText = text.getText();
            nextText = "\nWelcome!";
            surname = textProcessing.processText(textField, text,   
                currentText, nextText, vbox);
        }
    }  
}

public class TextProcessing {

private String userInput;
private String textToDisplay;

public TextProcessing() {
    userInput = "";
    textToDisplay = "";
}

public String processText(TextField textField, Text text, String     
    currentText, String nextText, VBox vbox) {
    textField.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        public void handle(KeyEvent key) {
            if (key.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                vbox.getChildren().remove(text);
                userInput = textField.getText();
                textToDisplay = currentText + "\n" + userInput + "\n" + 
                    nextText;
                textField.clear();
                text.setText(textToDisplay);
                vbox.getChildren().add(text);
                vbox.getChildren().remove(textField);
                vbox.getChildren().add(textField);
            }
        }
    });
    return userInput;
}
```

The firstname field in the Game Class isn't getting updated by the 
firstname = textProcessing.processText(textField, text, currentText, nextText, vbox); statement, and therefore the if statement is never true. I think it's likely I'm failing to understand how the EventHandler works - I want it to execute once and return the updated value, and then go into it again when I call surname = textProcessing.processText(textField, text, currentText, nextText, vbox);  I've spent hours on this and have tried searching for questions already asked that might help me, but I just haven't been able to figure out how to make it work. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does `textProcessing.processText()` do?

Comment: I've included the processText() method in the above code, it's in the TextProcessing Class at the bottom of my code. Thanks.

Comment: I am sure that when you are calling `surname = textProcessing.processText(textField, text, currentText, nextText, vbox);` you pass reference for the surname text instead of passing reference for the firstname text.

Comment: I'm not following. If all is working ok by this point, it should pass 
     `surname = textProcessing.processText(textField, text,   
                "What is your first name? \nJoe \nWhat is your surname?",     "\nWelcome", vbox);`